# C# how to reorder a List Tuple depending on values

Tags: c#, list

Our platform allows user to submit forms (Umbraco Forms), but upon opening the submitted forms, the order of the data fields has changed arbitrarily every time. I need to reorder a form to the original order, but cannot know the order of the form without iterating it. I have tried this:

```
// recordFields are all out of order; create a new List to store each value (in wrong order)
var extractedFields = new List<Tuple<string, string, string>>();
foreach (var field in record.RecordFields)
{
    var extractValue = field.Value.ValuesAsString().NullSafeToString();
    var extractType = CGHelper.CleanString(field.Value.Field.FieldType.Name).ToLower();
    var extractCaption = field.Value.Field.Caption;
    extractedFields.Add(new Tuple<string, string, string>(extractCaption, extractType, extractValue));
}

var count = 0;
foreach (var field in extractedFields.ToList())
{
    if (field.Item1 == "Opportunity ID")
    {
        extractedFields.Remove(field);
        extractedFields.Insert(0, field);
    }
    else if (field.Item1 == "Name")
    {
        extractedFields.Remove(field);
        extractedFields.Insert(1, field);
    }
    else if (field.Item1 == "Project/Study Title")
    {
        extractedFields.Remove(field);
        extractedFields.Insert(2, field);
    }
    else if (field.Item1 == "Project/Study Overview")
    {
        extractedFields.Remove(field);
        extractedFields.Insert(3, field);
    }
    else if (field.Item1 == "How were Voice members involved?")
    {
        extractedFields.Remove(field);
        extractedFields.Insert(4, field);
    }
    else if (field.Item1 == "How did Voice members help/influence your project?")
    {
        extractedFields.Remove(field);
        extractedFields.Insert(5, field);
    }
    else if (field.Item1 == "Project/Study Outcomes/Findings")
    {
        extractedFields.Remove(field);
        extractedFields.Insert(6, field);
    }
    else if (field.Item1 == "What will happen next with your research?")
    {
    extractedFields.Remove(field);
    extractedFields.Insert(7, field);
    }
    else if (field.Item1 == "Have any papers or reports been published as a result of the research project?")
    {
        extractedFields.Remove(field);
        extractedFields.Insert(8, field);
    }
    else if (field.Item1 == "If yes, please upload a copy here")
    {
        extractedFields.Remove(field);
        extractedFields.Insert(9, field);
    }
    else if (field.Item1.StartsWith("Photo to be"))
    {
        extractedFields.Remove(field);
        extractedFields.Insert(10, field);
    }
    else if (field.Item1 == "If further project information is available, please provide the link below")
    {
        extractedFields.Remove(field);
        extractedFields.Insert(11, field);
    }
    count++;
}
```

Upon finding the index with the relevant string, it removes that value and inserts it again at the correct index. This doesn't work though and actually results in this order I have put the index values in for where they **should** be):

```
[0] Opportunity ID
[1] Name
[2] Project study/title
[3] Project/Study Overview
[4] How were Voice members involved?
[6] Project/Study Outcomes/Findings
[7] What will happen next with your research?
[5] How did Voice members help/influence your project?
[8] Have any papers or reports been published as a result of the research project?
[9] If yes, please upload a copy here
[10] Photo to be displayed on the Voice website with your feedback. If possible, please attach a relevant photo from the project/study i.e. a picture of the research team, equipment etc, or the project/study logo
[11] If further project information is available, please provide the link below
```

This was the **original** order of `extractedFields`:

```
If further project information is available, please provide the link below
Name
Project study/title
What will happen next with your research?
How were Voice members involved?
Project/Study Outcomes/Findings
Have any papers or reports been published as a result of the research project?
If yes, please upload a copy here
How did Voice members help/influence your project?
Opportunity ID
Photo to be displayed on the Voice website with your feedback. If possible, please attach a relevant photo from the project/study i.e. a picture of the research team, equipment etc, or the project/study logo
Project/Study Overview
```

Comment: Just FYI `Tuple.Create` instead of `new Tuple` will allow you to skip explicitly specifiyng the generic parameters if you want that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a list with the right order and use Linq to order by the item index:

```
var rightOrder = new List<string>
{
    "Opportunity ID",
    "Name",
    "Project study/title",
    "Project/Study Overview",
    "How were Voice members involved?",
    "Project/Study Outcomes/Findings",
    "What will happen next with your research?",
    "How did Voice members help/influence your project?",
    "Have any papers or reports been published as a result of the research project?",
    "If yes, please upload a copy here",
    "Photo to be displayed on the Voice website with your feedback. If possible, please attach a relevant photo from the project/study i.e. a picture of the research team, equipment etc, or the project/study logo",
    "If further project information is available, please provide the link below"
};

extractedFields = extractedFields
    .OrderBy(x => rightOrder.IndexOf(x.Item1))
    .ToList();
```

Another option is use a dictionary instead of list:

```
var rightOrderDic= new Dictionary<string,int>
{
    {"Opportunity ID",0},
    {"Name",1},
    {"Project study/title",2},
    {"Project/Study Overview",3},
    {"How were Voice members involved?",4},
    {"Project/Study Outcomes/Findings",5},
    {"What will happen next with your research?",6},
    {"How did Voice members help/influence your project?",7},
    {"Have any papers or reports been published as a result of the research project?",8},
    {"If yes, please upload a copy here",9},
    {"Photo to be displayed on the Voice website with your feedback. If possible, please attach a relevant photo from the project/study i.e. a picture of the research team, equipment etc, or the project/study logo",10},
    {"If further project information is available, please provide the link below",11}
};
extractedFields = extractedFields
    .OrderBy(x=>rightOrderDic[x.Item1])
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, for some reason using the Linq method sorts all correctly with the exception of the long "Photo" string, which it always puts at position 0

Comment: @JohnDawson check if the string on the list or the dictionary is the same that the one you're receiving. It has to be the exact string.

Comment: Got it! Found the exact string from the JSON: "Photo to be displayed on the Voice website with your feedback.\n\nIf possible, please attach a relevant photo from the project/study i.e. a picture of the research team, equipment etc, or the project/study logo." - works now, thanks for your help!

Comment: @JohnDawson side note: The list option is better if there is an option that is not on the list, since it will return -1 and the item will be placed in the first position. The dictionary, on the other hand, will be faster to lookup, but if it finds a value that isn't in the dictionary, it will throw an exception.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `OrderBy` and provide some value representing order based on the condition:

```cs
extractedFields = extractedFields
    .OrderBy(field => field.Item1 switch 
    {
        "Opportunity ID" => 0,
        "Name" => 1,
        // ...
        _ => int.MaxValue
    })
    .ToList();
```

If language version you are using does not support pattern matching - you can use switch-case instead:

```cs
extractedFields = extractedFields
    .OrderBy(field =>
    {
        switch (field.Item1)
        {
                case "Opportunity ID":
                    return 0;
                case "Name":
                    return 1;
                // ...
                default: return int.MaxValue;
        }
    })
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work because when you insert at index 10, then you iterate again, changing the index of that element.

Try use a Dictionary maybe:

```
var dic = new Dictionary<int,Tuple<string, string, string>>();
foreach (var field in extractedFields.ToList())
  {
  if (field.Item1 == "Opportunity ID")
  {
      dic[0] = field;
  }
   ....
}
extractedFields.Clear();
for(int i=0; i<dic.Keys.Count; i++){
    extractedFields.Add(dic[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because insertion moves element in a list further (let's say we have list 1, 2, inserting at second postion 10 would mean pushing 2 at position 3, i.e. 1, 10, 2).

So you need some kind of mapping between those rules/texts and indexes. Please see below code:

```
 class Program
    {
        // We are using different string comparisons, so here we define some helper enum to distinct that.
        enum MatchOption
        {
            Exact,
            StartsWith,
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var rules = new List<Tuple<int, MatchOption, string>>()
            {
                new Tuple<int, MatchOption, string>(0, MatchOption.Exact, "Opportunity ID"),
                new Tuple<int, MatchOption, string>(1, MatchOption.Exact, "Name"),
                new Tuple<int, MatchOption, string>(2, MatchOption.Exact, "Project study/title"),
                new Tuple<int, MatchOption, string>(3, MatchOption.Exact, "Project/Study Overview"),
                new Tuple<int, MatchOption, string>(4, MatchOption.Exact, "How were Voice members involved?"),
                new Tuple<int, MatchOption, string>(6, MatchOption.Exact, "Project/Study Outcomes/Findings"),
                new Tuple<int, MatchOption, string>(7, MatchOption.Exact, "What will happen next with your research?"),
                new Tuple<int, MatchOption, string>(5, MatchOption.Exact, "How did Voice members help/influence your project?"),
                new Tuple<int, MatchOption, string>(8, MatchOption.Exact, "Have any papers or reports been published as a result of the research project?"),
                new Tuple<int, MatchOption, string>(9, MatchOption.Exact, "If yes, please upload a copy here"),
                new Tuple<int, MatchOption, string>(10, MatchOption.StartsWith, "Photo to be"),
                new Tuple<int, MatchOption, string>(11, MatchOption.Exact, "If further project information is available, please provide the link below"),
            };

            var extractedFields = new List<Tuple<string, string, string>>()
            {
                new Tuple<string,string,string>("If further project information is available, please provide the link below", string.Empty, string.Empty),
                new Tuple<string,string,string>("Name", string.Empty, string.Empty),
                new Tuple<string,string,string>("Project study/title", string.Empty, string.Empty),
                new Tuple<string,string,string>("What will happen next with your research?", string.Empty, string.Empty),
                new Tuple<string,string,string>("How were Voice members involved?", string.Empty, string.Empty),
                new Tuple<string,string,string>("Project/Study Outcomes/Findings", string.Empty, string.Empty),
                new Tuple<string,string,string>("Have any papers or reports been published as a result of the research project?", string.Empty, string.Empty),
                new Tuple<string,string,string>("If yes, please upload a copy here", string.Empty, string.Empty),
                new Tuple<string,string,string>("How did Voice members help/influence your project?", string.Empty, string.Empty),
                new Tuple<string,string,string>("Opportunity ID", string.Empty, string.Empty),
                new Tuple<string,string,string>("Photo to be displayed on the Voice website with your feedback. If possible, please attach a relevant photo from the project/study i.e. a picture of the research team, equipment etc, or the project/study logo", string.Empty, string.Empty),
                new Tuple<string,string,string>("Project/Study Overview", string.Empty, string.Empty),
            };
            var orderedList = new Tuple<string, string, string>[extractedFields.Count];

            foreach (var field in extractedFields)
            {
                // strong assumption here: entry will match exactly one rule
                var matchedRule = rules.Single((r) =>
                {
                    return r.Item2 switch
                    {
                        MatchOption.Exact => r.Item3 == field.Item1,
                        MatchOption.StartsWith => field.Item1.StartsWith(r.Item3),
                        _ => throw new InvalidOperationException("Unknown operation"),
                    };
                });
                // After matching rule, insert item at correct index.
                orderedList[matchedRule.Item1] = field;
            }
        }
    }
```